# How to split and extract from string in bash

Tags: bash

I have a string "prod-v4.38"

I want to split and get values like:

```
ENV_NAME=$(echo "$OLD_VERSION" | awk -F'-' '{print $1}')
VER_MAJOR=$(echo "$OLD_VERSION" | awk -F'-' '{print $2}')
VER_MINOR=$(echo "$OLD_VERSION" | awk -F'.' '{print $2}')

echo "ENV_NAME" $ENV_NAME
echo "VER_MAJOR" $VER_MAJOR
echo "VER_MINOR" $VER_MINOR
```

Which prints

```
ENV_NAME prod
VER_MAJOR v4.38
VER_MINOR 38
```

But I want to get:

```
ENV_NAME prod
VER_MAJOR 4
VER_MINOR 38
```

And then combine three to get `prod-v4.38`

Answer (score 4):

In bash, `[[ ... ]]` with the `=~` operator allows capturing portions of a regex expression that populates the system `BASH_REMATCH` array. You use parenthesis around the portions of the regex you wish to capture. The `BASH_REMATCH` array elements are the capture groups beginning with the second element (index `1`). The first element holds the entire regex matched.

In your case with your version string in the variable `str` you would have:

```bash
[[ $str =~ ^([^-]+)-([^.]+)[.](.*)$ ]]
```

To use it in your bash script, just make sure the expression matches what is in `str`, either with an `if` or *compound-command*. A short example would be:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

str="prod-v4.38"

[[ $str =~ ^([^-]+)-([^.]+)[.](.*)$ ]] || {
  printf "error: '%s' not valid version string.\n"
  exit 1
}

printf "ENV_NAME: %s\nVER_MAJOR: %s\nVER_MINOR: %s\n" \
"${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
```

**output**

```
$ bash split-ver.sh
ENV_NAME: prod
VER_MAJOR: v4
VER_MINOR: 38
```

If you need to make it POSIX shell compatible, you can simply use the *parameter expansions*, e.g.

```bash
ENV_NAME="${str%-*}"
tmp="${str#"$ENV_NAME"-}"
VER_MAJOR="${tmp%.*}"
VER_MINOR="${tmp#*.}"
```

Answer (score 3):

Use parameter expansion, it's much faster than shelling out to `awk`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
old_version='prod-v4.32'
env_name=${old_version%-*}  # Remove "-*" from the right.

version=${old_version#*-v}  # Remove "*-v" from the left.
ver_major=${version%.*}
ver_minor=${version#*.}

echo ENV_NAME "$env_name"
echo VER_MAJOR "$ver_major"
echo VER_MINOR "$ver_minor"
```

How you could have got 38 from the string containing 32 I have no idea, but maybe that was a typo?

Answer (score 2):

also check it out :

```
OLD_VERSION="prod-v4.38"

IFS='-.' read -r ENV_NAME VER_MAJOR VER_MINOR <<< "$OLD_VERSION"

VER_MAJOR=${VER_MAJOR#v}

echo "ENV_NAME" "$ENV_NAME"
echo "VER_MAJOR" "$VER_MAJOR"
echo "VER_MINOR" "$VER_MINOR"

NEW_VERSION="${ENV_NAME}-v${VER_MAJOR}.${VER_MINOR}"
echo "NEW_VERSION" "$NEW_VERSION"
```

output

```
ENV_NAME prod
VER_MAJOR 4
VER_MINOR 38
NEW_VERSION prod-v4.38
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using single `read`:

```bash
oldVer="prod-v4.38"
IFS="-." read version verMajor verMinor <<< "$oldVer"
verMajor="${verMajor//[!0-9]}"

# check 3 variables
declare -p version verMajor verMinor

declare -- version="prod"
declare -- verMajor="4"
declare -- verMinor="38"

# combine 3 to get original string
printf -v newVer "%s-v%s.%s" "$version" "$verMajor" "$verMinor"

# check new variable
declare -p newVer

declare -- newVer="prod-v4.38"
```

Answer (score 1):

`read` is simpler.

```
$ old=prod-v4.38

$ IFS=".-" read -r environ major minor <<< "$old"
$: echo "environ='$environ' major='${major#v}' minor='$minor'"
environ='prod' major='4' minor='38'

$ IFS=".-" read -ra field <<< "$old"
$ echo "env:${field[0]} maj:${field[1]#v} min:${field[2]}"
env:prod maj:4 min:38
```

As a rule, any time you see yourself repeating the same thing, you should probably refactor.
Even this would be better:

```
$ mapfile -t field < <( awk -F'[-.]' -v OFS=$'\n' '{print $1,$2,$3}' <<< "$old" )

$ echo "env:${field[0]} maj:${field[1]#v} min:${field[2]}"
env:prod maj:4 min:38
```